# Does Amazon SNS use GET or POST to an http subscription?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I could not find anything documentation regarding method or format of message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) is using a HTTP POST to deliver a notification message, see the FAQ [What are the different delivery formats/transports for receiving notifications?](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#13):

> - “HTTP”, “HTTPS” – Subscribers specify a URL as part of the
>     subscription registration; notifications will be delivered through an
>     HTTP POST to the specified URL.

The notification message format is documented in [HTTP/HTTPS Notifications JSON Format](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/json-formats.html#http-notification-json) (the *Subscribe/Unsubscribe JSON Formats* are documented in [Appendix D: JSON Formats](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sns/latest/gsg/json-formats.html) as well).